# Limitations of block proposal tips paid to Validator's fee recipient?

Tags: solidity, evm, proof-of-stake, clients, validators

I'm trying to find out the limitations of the block proposal tips paid out to validator's fee recipient on the execution layer. Like being sent to a smart contract with a fallback/receive function. What are the gas limits on these tips?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Builder tips you're talking about aren't received via a transaction that calls the recipient. They are just added to the balance of the fee recipient address when the block is created, your fallback/receive function wont be called by it, so the gas usage isn't a factor

You could make the recipient a contract that collects the fees and has a function you can call to execute whatever logic you need though

Comment: Awesome that explains so much. Thank you!